# Can a pendulum have detectable harmonic frequencies

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, frequency, oscillators, harmonics

Can a pendulum produce harmonic frequencies? Like could I detect harmonic frequencies if I had a sensor on the pendulum?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  You can measure the period of the pendulum with a stopwatch and thereby get the natural frequency of vibration.  Are you talking about the fact that a pendulum is anharmonic in the sense that's it doesn't undergo simple harmonic motion, and so its motion is decomposed as a sum of sinusoidal functions with different frequencies? Then, just measure the position as a function of time with a motion sensor and take the Fourier transform of the signal. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @march I think the OP means harmonic frequency of sound generated due to movement (the first second third harmonics) but I might be wrong too

Comment: The simple answer is... yes. It is actually very hard to make mechanical and electronic systems without detectable harmonics. A simple string pendulum is not a linear system, so it will definitely have harmonics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FlatterMann commented it’s a non-linear oscillator, when amplitudes are big enough. (I.e. when the approximation $\tan \phi \approx \phi$ no longer holds good enough.)

So you need two things:

- any kind of sensor, which is sensitive enough, like position, acceleration etc. AND produces an electric signal
- an FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) algorithm.

The FFT shows you the spectrum of the pendulum. The sensor must also be linear enough to avoid introducing artifacts. The FFT must be able to process these frequencies, which are very low compared to audio signals.

Answer (score 0):

If we speak of sound, I imagine one could have some sort of electronic diapazon on it? As for mouvement, my guess would be that one would need a xyz space positionner/reader/gps/whatever (like a gyroscope?) and to extract them out of the datas.

However, we'd need extra details to answer your question correctly.